# TFS 2018 installation over HTTPS

Tags: tfs

I am installing TFS 2018 in a Windows machine, using https.

I have a certificate for my domain, issued to `*.domain.org`.

I wanted to access TFS using this URL: `https://alm.domain.org/tfs`.

When I was trying to install TFS I realized I could change the public URL to: `https://alm.domain.org` but NOT to `https://alm.domain.org/tfs`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: 2018 will retain `/tfs` for upgrades, but will install itself in the root for fresh installations...

Comment: So I can't access TFS using https://alm.domain.org/tfs? Only whithout the /tfs?

Comment: That's the new location. I think they knew they wanted to rename TFS to another product name for soem time now ;). Team Foundation Server 2018 has been superseded by Azure DevOps Server 2019 (same product, new name, few new features).